# Angular JS add new row in editable mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating a grid using the ng-repeat directive. I need to be able to edit inline, which I achieved using the same idea provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915184/angularjs-inline-edit-inside-of-ng-repeat/19916739#19916739). 
I now also need to be able to add new rows to this grid on click of a button. I am doing this by pushing a new entry to my collection on each button click, which inserts a new row into my grid. I want this new row to get added in editable mode. However, to do that, I need to be able to set the `editMode` property to `true` dynamically while pushing the new row. How can I achieve this?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Thw8n/69/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did everything right, except binding to editMode field. Just change

data-ng-show="editMode"

to

data-ng-show="entry.editMode"

Comment: thanks, it works for adding a new row, but now I have a new problem. The Cancel button requires 2 clicks to reset the row, and I can't figure out why. The first click resets the data, the second replaces the textboxes with the labels.
http://jsfiddle.net/Thw8n/86/

Answer (score 2):

if i understand your problem in right way the following will be answer .

Just replace **editMode**  with **enty.editMode** in your html handlebars.

I was applied this solution to the your jsfiddle it is working fine for me.