# ngrepeat Edit in line with form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to allow renaming of an item in a line. I am aware of using $scope.editMode etc, but I realized that when I use this for ng-repeats I am getting all of the entries in the list as edditable rather than the specific index. Here is what I have in my Html:

```
      <li ng-repeat="playlist in myPlaylist">

        <a href="" data-ng-hide="editPlaylist">{{playlist.name}}</a>

          <form data-ng-show="editPlaylist" data-ng-submit="renamePlaylist()">
            <input data-ng-model="editablePlaylistName">
              </form>
      </li>
```

My controller uses context menu setting as so:

```
 $scope.editPlaylist =false;

 $scope.menuOptions = [
['Rename', function ($itemScope) {
    $scope.editPlaylist = true;
    $scope.editablePlaylistName = $itemScope.playlist.name;
}]
```

etc. When I want to rename, I am setting the hide and shows to true/false accordingly, but my issue is that all of the items in the list are true resulting a number of input fields for each item. How would I go around to only show an input field for the corresponding $index of the list? I followed a similar post [AngularJS inline edit inside of ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915184/angularjs-inline-edit-inside-of-ng-repeat), but wasn't able to identify why theirs was able to only show an input field for the corresponding $index. An image is shown below:

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to set the 'edit' flag on each repeatable item.

Markup:

```
<li ng-repeat="playlist in myPlaylist">
  <a data-ng-hide="playlist.isEditMode" ng-click="playlist.isEditMode=true">
    {{playlist.name}}
  </a>
  <form data-ng-show="playlist.isEditMode" data-ng-submit="renamePlaylist()">
    <input data-ng-model="playlist.name">
  </form>
</li>
```

I'm not sure I understand what your controller code does, but here's what it might look like:

```
$scope.myPlaylist = [...];
$scope.renamePlaylist = function() {
  //do whatever you do to rename play list 
  this.playlist.isEditMode = false;
};
```

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jbHdWKwTudjNcaInrS8V?p=preview) , hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

set blur as true in controller and use

```
<li ng-repeat="playlist in myPlaylist">
    <input type="text" value="{{playlist.name}}" ng-blur="blur=true;" ng-show="!blur"/>
    <span ng-focus="blur=false;" ng-show="blur">{{playlist.name}}</span>
</li>
```

also, do not forget to focus on the input on span focus. sorry for typos and short answer as written on mobile.